# OpenMP C++: Overlapping computations with communications

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads, openmp

I need to read a file in chunks. Since I am reading it in chunks, I thought I could parallelize the communications with computations. 
I need three active threads, such that while T1 is reading data, T2 could be processing, and T3 could be writing at the same time.

So far, I have managed to create three local buffers where I read the data from a file and store it in these local buffers. I take N elements from the file. Every time I reach N elements, I change thread_id, which means that next thread should store the next elements to its corresponding local buffer.

The #pragma omp critical make sure that while one thread is processing or writing data, no other thread is doing the same. However, if T1 is processing its chunk of data, T2 can write its output. This makes sure that the input is read and written correctly.

What I have so far is this:

```
int i = 0;
int thread_id = 0;
while (input_file >> stream_element) { 
        if(thread_id == 0) {
            input_buffer_1[i] = stream_element;
        }
        else if (thread_id == 1) {
            input_buffer_2[i] = stream_element;
        }
        else
            input_buffer_3[i] = stream_element;

        i++;

        if(i == N) {
            i = 0;
            if(thread_id == 0) {
                #pragma omp critical (processing_data)
                process(input_buffer_1, output_buffer_1, N);

                #pragma omp critical (writing_data)
                write(output_file, output_buffer_1, N);
            }
            else if(thread_id == 1) {
                #pragma omp critical (processing_data)
                process(input_buffer_2, output_buffer_2, N);

                #pragma omp critical (writing_data)
                write(output_file, output_buffer_2, N);
            }
            else {
                #pragma omp critical (processing_data)
                process(input_buffer_3, output_buffer_3, N);

                #pragma omp critical (writing_data)
                write(output_file, output_buffer_3, N);
            }
            thread_id++;
            if(thread_id == STREAM_THREADS)
                thread_id = 0;
        }
```

What would be the best way to initiate three threads and do these tasks in parallel and synchronized manner?

A simple visualization of the desired result is shown below.

[image]

Best regards,
Suejb

Comment: The fundamental flaw with the approach you propose is that OpenMP is not well suited to that type of computation.  Yes, I am sure that you can bend it to your will but you will always be struggling against the grain.  OpenMP's sweet spot is the type of computation in which each of a number of threads runs the same code on different parts of in-memory data.  If you wish to pursue your goals, investigate the `sections` construct, which strikes me as a better place to start than all those `critical`s.

Comment: Hi @HighPerformanceMark. Thank you for your response. I have realized that it will be difficult to implement this with OpenMP. I am now investigating the use of posix threads to finish the job. Furthermore, rather than having three different threads to do multiple different tasks, I am considering to have T1 that only reads data, T2 does the processing, and T3 the writing. Such that, when T1 reads some data, it notifies T2 to process it. Then T2 notifies T3 that data is ready to be written and T1 that data is not needed anymore.

Comment: Your revised approach seems a bit more straightforward, though you may want to ensure that threads 1 and 3 don't fight over access to the single read/write head on your disk.

Comment: Oh, and you've tested to ensure that each operation (reading, processing and writing) on each chunk takes approximately the same time so that all threads are approximately fully busy all the time, once the pipeline is full that is ?

Comment: No, thread one and 1 wont fight for the same access, because basically one chunk that is read from T1, will be stored in a local buffer for processing, and afterwards T3 will write it to the disk (a separate file).

Comment: With regards to load balancing, not necessarily reading, writing, and processing should take the same amount of time. At least I can not guarantee it, because it depends on the calculations performed on the processing part. But still, having this overlapping should reduce the makespan compared to performing reading, processing, and writing by a single thread.